# LDAP Connection/ Apache DS / Java

Tags: java, ldap, apache-directory

i wanted to make an easy LDAP Connection with using Apache DS and Java, wanted to learn and play a bit with authentification. However, when i start using the my jar file, i always get this error message:

```
Setting up LDAP connection ... 
LDAPException(resultCode=91 (connect error), errorMessage='An error occurred while attempting to resolve address 'ldap://localhost:10389':  
UnknownHostException(Der angegebene Host ist unbekannt (ldap://localhost:10389)), ldapSDKVersion=6.0.0, revision=524c20f3bbcc0d83fb56b9e136a2fd3a7f60437d')
```

My apache DS LDAP server looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwqE0.png)

My Java code:

```
package ldap.test;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

import javax.net.SocketFactory;

import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.BindRequest;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.BindResult;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.Filter;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPException;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPSearchException;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.ResultCode;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.SearchRequest;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.SearchResult;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.SearchResultEntry;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.SearchScope;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.SimpleBindRequest;
import com.unboundid.util.ssl.SSLUtil;
import com.unboundid.util.ssl.TrustAllTrustManager;

public final class App2 {
    // hostname of the ldap instance
      public static final String HOSTNAME = "ldap://localhost:10389";
      
      // port of the ldap instance
      public static final int PORT = 10389;
      
      public static final void main(String[] args)
      {
        // lazy hack
        if ( args.length != 4 ) {
          System.out.println("One or more parameters are missing!");
          System.out.println("java -jar App2.jar $cn $sn $employeenumber $password");
          System.out.println("Example: java -jar App2.jar Max Mustermann 1 1");
          System.exit(1);
        }

        // Use no key manager, and trust all certificates. This should not be used in non-trivial code!
        SSLUtil sslUtil = new SSLUtil(null, new TrustAllTrustManager());

        SocketFactory socketFactory;
        LDAPConnection ldapConnection = null;
        try {
          // Create the socket factory that will be used to make a secure
          // connection to the server.
          socketFactory = sslUtil.createSSLSocketFactory();
          System.out.print("Setting up LDAP connection ... ");
          ldapConnection = new LDAPConnection(socketFactory, HOSTNAME, PORT);
          System.out.println("done!");
        }
        catch ( LDAPException ldapException ) {
          System.err.println(ldapException);
          System.exit(ldapException.getResultCode().intValue());
        }
        catch ( GeneralSecurityException exception ) {
          System.err.println(exception);
          System.exit(1);
        }

        // LDAP bindrequest and actual bind for DN search
        System.out.print("Search DN for user with employeeNumber: " + args[2] + " ... ");
        BindRequest ldapBind = new SimpleBindRequest(args[0], args[1]);
        try {
          // bind with technical user and password and search for DN
          ldapConnection.bind(ldapBind);
          String employeeNumber = args[2];
          String userPassword = args[3];
          Filter ldapFilter = Filter.createANDFilter(Filter.createEqualityFilter("number", employeeNumber));
          SearchRequest searchReq = new SearchRequest("ou=users,o=Beispiel", SearchScope.SUB, ldapFilter, "dn");
          SearchResult searchResult;
          String foundDN = "none";
          try
          {
            searchResult = ldapConnection.search(searchReq);
            System.out.println("done!");
            for ( SearchResultEntry entry : searchResult.getSearchEntries() )
            {
              foundDN = entry.getDN();
            }
          }
          catch ( LDAPSearchException lse )
          {
            System.out.println("... error!");
            // The search failed for some reason
            searchResult = lse.getSearchResult();
            ResultCode resultCode = lse.getResultCode();
            System.out.println("Resultcode: " + resultCode);
            String errorMessageFromServer = lse.getDiagnosticMessage();
            System.out.println("Error message from server: " + errorMessageFromServer);
          }

          // now check for the foundDN if the given password is correct
          if ( !foundDN.equals("none") ) {
            System.out.println("Found DN for user with EmployeeNumber: " + employeeNumber + " => " + foundDN);
            System.out.println("Now checking if password for user is correct!");
            BindRequest userBindReq = new SimpleBindRequest(foundDN, userPassword);
            BindResult userBindRes = ldapConnection.bind(userBindReq);
            System.out.println("Result: " + userBindRes);
          }
          else {
            System.out.println("No DN found for user with EmployeeNumber: " + employeeNumber);
          }

        }
        catch ( LDAPException ldapException ) {
          System.err.println(ldapException);
          System.exit(ldapException.getResultCode().intValue());
        }
        finally {
          // Close ldap connection
          ldapConnection.close();
        }
      }
    }
```

No idea why i cant connect to the server...

-----Edit--------

When i change the HOSTNAME to localhost, i get the following error message:

```
Setting up LDAP connection ... LDAPException(resultCode=91 (connect error),
errorMessage='An error occurred while attempting to connect to server localhost:10389:  IOException(LDAPException(resultCode=91 (connect error), 
errorMessage='An error occurred while attempting to establish a connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:10389:  SSLException(Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message), 
ldapSDKVersion=6.0.0, revision=524c20f3bbcc0d83fb56b9e136a2fd3a7f60437d'))')
```

Well the good thing is that he can find localhost, but he cant connect to the server

Comment: It looks like you defined the HOSTNAME in the code with a protocol prefix (ldap) and a port. I suspect the `new LDAPConnection(...)` wants `localhost` as the HOSTNAME (without the protocol and port).

Comment: yeah i thought this would be the case too,  however i get the next error message ( edited on the original post)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, and the problem was solved by calling the LDAPConnection constructor with only two arguments ("localhost",10389). Could you check if this resolves your issue too?

Ofcourse, you should also remove the "ldap//:" prefix too!